# Select users who don't have projects assigned in specific date, Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 3 tables: Projects, Employees and Assignments. Employees are assigned to different projects and projects can take some time. I need to find an employee who will be free on a specific day (won't have a project assigned).

```
CREATE TABLE Employee (
  id NUMBER(10) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,  
  name VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL
  );
  
CREATE TABLE Projects (
  id NUMBER(10) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
  start_date DATE NOT NULL,
  end_date DATE NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO 
Employee(id, name) VALUES (1, 'Joe Doe');
         
INSERT INTO 
Employee(id, name) VALUES (2, 'Alex Doe');

INSERT INTO  
Projects(id, name, start_date, end_date) 
         VALUES (1, 'AAA',
                 TO_DATE('2020/12/30 00:00:00', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss'),
                 TO_DATE('2021/06/30 00:00:00', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss'));
                 
INSERT INTO  
Projects(id, name, start_date, end_date) 
         VALUES (2, 'BBB',
                 TO_DATE('2020/11/30 00:00:00', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss'),
                 TO_DATE('2021/03/30 00:00:00', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss'));
                 
INSERT INTO  
Projects(id, name, start_date, end_date) 
         VALUES (3, 'CCC',
                 TO_DATE('2020/11/10 00:00:00', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss'),
                 TO_DATE('2020/11/30 00:00:00', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss'));
                 
CREATE TABLE Assignments (
  id NUMBER(10) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  employee_id NUMBER(10) NOT NULL,
  project_id NUMBER(10) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT employee_fk FOREIGN KEY (employee_id) REFERENCES Employee(id),
  CONSTRAINT project_fk FOREIGN KEY (project_id) REFERENCES Projects(id)
 );
 
INSERT INTO Assignments(id, project_id, employee_id)
VALUES (1, 1, 1);

INSERT INTO Assignments(id, project_id, employee_id)
VALUES (2, 1, 2);

INSERT INTO Assignments(id, project_id, employee_id)
VALUES (3, 2, 1);

INSERT INTO Assignments(id, project_id, employee_id)
VALUES (4, 3, 1);
```

I know how to check people and their projects, but I need help with month and day condition. Let's say this specific day is 24th of March. I came up with something like this, but it's not what I want - because I guess I need somehow check if a free day is not in project duration time - am I right? How to do this?

```
SELECT Employee.name, Projects.name
FROM Assignments
INNER JOIN Employee ON Employee.id = Assignments.employee_id 
INNER JOIN Projects ON Projects.id = Assignments.project_id 
WHERE EXTRACT(month FROM Projects.start_date) < 3 AND
EXTRACT(day FROM Projects.start_date) >  24
GROUP BY Employee.name, Projects.name;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f483d/4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `DATE` literal to create the date and check if the employee is free on the specific date using the `EXISTS` as follows:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Employee.name FROM Assignments
  INNER JOIN Employee ON Employee.id = Assignments.employee_id 
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Projects 
                    WHERE Projects.id = Assignments.project_id 
                     AND DATE '2020-03-24' 
                         BETWEEN Projects.START_date AND Projects.end_date);
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f483d/8)

You can also use `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` as follows:

```
SELECT Employee.name FROM Assignments
  INNER JOIN Employee ON Employee.id = Assignments.employee_id 
  INNER JOIN Projects ON Projects.id = Assignments.project_id 
 GROUP BY Employee.name
 HAVING COUNT (CASE WHEN DATE '2020-03-24' 
                         BETWEEN Projects.START_date 
                         AND Projects.end_date 
               THEN 1 END) = 0
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f483d/9)